# How to force GDB to start number breakpoints at 1

Tags: c++, gdb, breakpoints

How can I force GDB to start its numbering of newly added breakpoints at 1, after I have deleted all breakpoints with the [delete](https://sourceware.org/gdb/current/onlinedocs/gdb/Delete-Breaks.html#:%7E:text=delete%20%5Bbreakpoints%5D%20%5Blist%E2%80%A6%5D) command?

I'm using this version of GDB: `GNU gdb (GDB) 8.0.50.20171024-git`

### TL;DR Rationale

During complicated debug sessions, I have a separate command file that I use the [source command](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Command-Files.html#:%7E:text=source%20%5B%2Ds%5D%20%5B%2Dv%5D%20filename) to source back in, with the first line of that command being `delete br`. That does clear the breakpoints as it should. Then, in subsequent lines, I add the complicated breakpoints, but does not restart with breakpoint 1.  That means that, during a the same debug session, and *without* exiting and restarting the whole GDB session again, GDB will continue numbering the breakpoints at the next integer *after* the last one that was added before, but then was deleted.  Yes, I could restart the GDB session, sure, and that is a workaround, but that is suboptimal because it forces me to wait for GDB to reload the executable into core, and the executable is quite large (yes, that is indeed a problem, but is **not** the droids we are discussing right now).  Then, I want to add, to that command file, commands to disable all breakpoints *except* the first one, then manually use `continue` to continue to the first breakpoint, and *only then* re-enable the subsequent breakpoints. Then once those are added in, I want to execute specifically the command (which shall be hardcoded into my wetware and never ever be changed): `enable 2-20`. Because then I want to discover some code, then use the `disable 2-20` command (also hardcoded in my wetware) followed by the `run` command, and repeat ad infinitum, all **without** having to restart GDB.

Side note: Please do not ask me to program in GDB's Python. Yes, I know how. But I don't wanna.  This should be something built-into plain 'ole GDB without any extra Python coding chores/requirements.  *But* if you do have a Python based approach, I will reluctantly listen and so too maybe even accept it as the answer.

Comment: Nope. How do I know? *I looked in the source*. Now if you want to fix the source, that's not very hard; and if you want to send a pull request, you can do that too. But out of the box, no.

Comment: Instead of hardcoding breakpoint numbers, you could use [`$bpnum`](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Set-Breaks.html) instead.

Comment: An alternative to using `disable` and `enable` is to create conditional breakpoints that depend on the value of a convenience variable that you can set or toggle during the debug session. `break "foo.c":24 if $flag`

Comment: @ssbssa I already use `$bpnum` quite heavily already, but that does not solve the problem of monotonically increasing breakpoint numbering that GDB does when sourcing files that clear in an add new breakpoints.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick I use conditional breakpoints heavily. That also does not solve the problem caused by monotonically increasing breakpoint numbering.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. So it is not possible without a code change. Understood. I'm not interested in spending time patching the GDB source for this, at least not right at the moment.

Comment: If you remember the `$bpnum` of the first and last breakpoints you want to disable/enable, then you could do something like `disable $myfirstbp-$mylastbp`. Why does this not solve the problem?

Comment: The easiest fix is probably to *not* remove all the breakpoints, and have your script only add them if they're not already set.

Comment: @ssbssa that does not solve the problem, because a requirement is to be able to change the command repeatedly.

Comment: @ChrisDodd that might work, but only if the command language for GDB would allow you to test to see if a breakpoint exists. But it does not meet the requirement of allowing me to delete all breakpoints and and sourcing the file again. So, for now, I believe we will just have to wait for someone to come up with a viable answer, and post the answer.

Comment: That's not what it says in the question, it specifically states: `which shall be hardcoded into my wetware and never ever be changed`.

Comment: @ssbssa: I stand corrected: My OP implies that my wetware had to hardcode _exactly_ the GDB command: `enable 2-20`. That was taking it too far, indeed. I should have stated the exact limits of that wetware hardcoding. No matter, both you ssbsa, and Chris Dodd are obviously now my superior wetware reprogrammers. "I'm not worthy, I'm not worthy ...". I also see [Chris Dodd's `ei` and `di` commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73173302/257924) which are superior to my current choice of `enable 2-20`, because they are only **two characters long** and thus much easier to remember.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your use-case described in your rationale, you're probably best off *not* trying to get the breakpoints assigned to specific numbers and instead use [convenience vars](https://sourceware.org/gdb/onlinedocs/gdb/Convenience-Vars.html) to keep track of the breakpoint numbers.

Whenever you set a breakpoint, gdb will set `$bpnum` to the number of the breakpoint.  You can save that value to another convenience var for later use.  So your script would end up with something like:

```
break foo   # the first breakpoint you always want active
break bar   # the first you want to enable/disable
set $first_interesting = $bpnum
break baz   # some more interesting ones
break box
break bap
set $last_interesting = $bpnum

define ei
    enable $first_interesting-$last_interesting
end
document ei
    enable the interesting breakpoints
end
define di
    disable $first_interesting-$last_interesting
end
document di
    disable the interesting breakpoints
end
```

Now you just need to remember the commands `ei`/`di` in your wetware...

Comment: Yes. This is **The Way**.  Reference [prior discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73127178/how-to-force-gdb-to-start-number-breakpoints-at-1?noredirect=1#comment129253145_73127178) for why.